# Angular UpdateTag is working fine in inspection element but not showing meta tag changes in page view source

Tags: angular, typescript, metadata, meta-tags

I am using Angular 13. I have set default meta tag in index.html file. I have successfully updated the meta tag using the `updateTag` event but It works fine in the inspect element but does not update the view source page. I want to set dynamic information in meta tag using API call. When I check by inspect, it will show updated data but when I share the link on Facebook it will not reflect updated data.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule, Meta } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module'; 

import {CoreModule } from './core/core.module';
import {HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS} from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    CoreModule,
  ],
  providers: [Meta]
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Title Example</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">

  <link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/" />
  <meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
  <meta name="description"
    content="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry." />
  <meta name="keywords" content="test example, lorem ipsum">
  <meta property="og:url" content="https://example.com/" />
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="ExampleSite" />
  <meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
  <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
  <meta property="og:title" content="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text." />
  <meta property="og:description"
    content="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry." />
  <meta property="og:image" content="https://example.com/assets/logo/socialshare.png" />

  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
 
</head>

<body>
  <app-root>
  </app-root>
</body>

</html>
```

**service.ts**

```
import { Injectable,Inject  } from '@angular/core';
import { Title, Meta, MetaDefinition  } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SeoService {

  constructor(
    private metaTagService: Meta,
    private title: Title,
    private router: Router,
  ) {
   }

  updateTitle(title: string){
    this.title.setTitle(title);
  }

  updateTags(metaTags: MetaDefinition[]){
    metaTags.forEach(m=> this.metaTagService.updateTag(m));
  }
  
  updateTag(obj :any){
    this.metaTagService.updateTag(obj)
  }
}
```

**Update tag on test.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';
import { Service } from 'src/app/service.service';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile',
  templateUrl: './profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile.component.scss']
})
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {
 
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private seo: Service
  ) {
   }

  ngOnInit(): void {
   this.updateTags()
  }

   updateTags(){
    this.seo.updateCanonicalUrl(environment.RouterBaseUrl + this.router.url)
    this.seo.updateTitle(test + ' - Profile')
    this.seo.updateTags([
      { name: 'description', content: 'Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book'},
      { property: 'og:url', content: environment.RouterBaseUrl + this.router.url},
      { property: 'og:title', content: test + ' - Profile'},
      { property: 'og:description', content: 'Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book'},
      { property: 'og:image', content: https://example.com/assets/images/test.png },
    ]);
   }
}
```

Comment: What is displayed in your view source page ? Do you use Angular Universal ? Because, the meta tags in the view source page, can be only be change using server-side-rendering.

Comment: @user1075296  No I didn't use Angular Universal. Is it not possible to be a client-side?

Comment: No, you can not do that on client side. The view source page will always have the value inside your index.htlml file. Ps: If you use Angular Universal, do not forget to use Renderer2. (Not for you current case, but I am sure you will need it).